# What does the word "these" refer to in the given paragraph?

Tags: pronouns

> We will have to devise innovative plans to ensure that minorities,
>   particularly the Muslim minority, are empowered to share equitably the
>   fruits of development. **These** must have the first claim on
>   resources

Does the word these refer to the "*minorities*" or does it refer to the "*innovative plans*"?

Answer (score 2):

'These' could refer to plans. The passage you quote is an excellent example of why it is a bad idea to begin sentences with 'These' or 'This' not followed with the appropriate noun. So, here, it would have been better to write "These **plans**..." or "These **minorities**..." and remove any doubt in the reader's mind.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to "minorities". I can only tell because of the context, not the sentence structure (it doesn't make sense for "fruits of development" to have a claim on resources).